# How to create a redux store actionSanitizer when using PayloadActions?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, redux-devtools, redux-actions

I am trying to create an actionSanitizer to be used with devTools when configuring a store for redux. The problem is that stores are slices created with createSlice and there the reducers are defined as

```js
createSlice({
  name: 'Something',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
   someReducer(
     state,
     action: PayloadAction<SomeType>
   ) {
    /** Do something **/
   }
  }
})
```

Now the action is of type `PayloadAction`.

```js
// From redux toolkits createAction.d.ts
export declare type PayloadAction<P = void, T extends string = string, M = never, E = never> = {
    payload: P;
    type: T;
} & ([M] extends [never] ? {} : {
    meta: M;
}) & ([E] extends [never] ? {} : {
    error: E;
});
```

actionSanitizer only accepts functions with type

```js
  actionSanitizer?: <A extends Action>(action: A, id: number) => A;
```

This works, but obviously is not what I want

```js
const devToolsConfiguration: DevToolsEnhancerOptions = {
  name: 'Qwerty',
  actionSanitizer: action => action,
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk, logger],
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : devToolsConfiguration
});
```

But then this solution, which tries to follow few other examples ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67627569/256965), [2](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/master/docs/API/Arguments.md#actionsanitizer--statesanitizer)) doesn't, because the types are not compatible

```js
const devToolsConfiguration: DevToolsEnhancerOptions = {
  name: 'Qwerty',
  actionSanitizer: (action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
    action.type === "someAction" && action.data
    ? return { ...action, payload: '<<LONG_BLOB>>' }
    : action
  },
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk, logger],
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : devToolsConfiguration
});
```

So they don't seem to be compatible at all. How can I write a action sanitizer for the actions now?

---

Answer (score 0):

Your action creators have a `.match` function:

```js
actionSanitizer: (action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
    return someActionCreatorFromASlice.match(action)
    ? { ...action, payload: '<<LONG_BLOB>>' }
    : action

``
```

Comment: The true part `{ ...action, payload: <<LONG_BLOB>> }` still isn't assignable to the return type of actionSanitizer. `Type '(action: PayloadAction<any>) => { payload: any; type: string; }' is not assignable to type '<A extends Action<any>>(action: A, id: number) => A'.`, because the actionSanitizer is typed so that it expects to get back only the action

Comment: Then you probably won't get around a `as any` on that return statement.

By the way, the `return` was in the workg place, I'm gonna update that